# Sql server execution on dedicated vs shared servers

Tags: sql-server

I have Sql Server Management Studio 2008 installed on a dedicated server with total System RAM of 16 GB allocated to SSMS. Whereas i have another SSMS installed on a shared Windows server with 32 GB RAM allocated to SSMS out of 128 GB total server RAM.

Is there an issue when we use SSMS to run heavy queries on a shared Windows server as compared to running the same queries of SSMS on a dedicated Windows server.

By dedicated i mean the Windows Server has only SSMS running and some very small applications.Here only SSMS is using whole of Server RAM.

By shared i mean the Windows Server has many heavy applications like Spotfire, Hadoop, Linux along with SSMS. All the other applications are concurrently running of shared Windows server.

Actually, when i run a query on dedicated server it takes 70 mins to execute whereas the same query takes ~300 mins in a shared server where other users are also using the server at the same time.

Please suggest me with solutions to resolve this.

Thanks!

Comment: Why would anyone install SSMS on a server? It's a SQL _client_ not a database engine. And what kind of files do you edit that your SQL _client_ needs a whopping 128GB RAM?

Comment: I'm voting to move this to DBA, as it's not about programming.

Comment: I think OP meant `sql server 2008` wherever they've written `ssms`. @a_horse_with_no_name.